# ArgoCD stuck in deleting resource

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I’m having an issue where ArgoCD when deleting the resources is getting stuck because it tries to delete the child’s first and then the parents.
This works well for some cases but I have cases where this doesn’t work for instance, certificates.. it deletes the certificate request but because the certificate still exists it recreated the certificate request.
And it just stays there deleting and recreating :/

Is there a a way to specify an order or just tell Argo to delete it all at once?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share what is the `syncPolicy` specified in your Application resource definition and more importantly what does `metadata.finalizers` look like?

Answer (score -1):

Yup so... here is the all thing:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: previews
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  project: previews
  source:
    repoURL: git@github.com:myrepo.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: helm
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: previews
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      selfHeal: true
      prune: true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).